# Form has Disabled Inputs, How to make Processing Page not try to process disabled fields?

Tags: forms

I have a form where I disable the Shipping address when they click the "Same as Billing address" checkbox via JQuery.

When the form is submitted, the disabled fields (shipping) obviously do not pass any data but my processing form is saying that those specific fields are undefined.

How can I make the processing form not look for the values of the disabled fields (shipping), if they are disabled?

HERE IS THE PROCESSING FORM:

```
<cfset orderno = #numberFormat(randrange(00001,99999), "00000")#>
<cfmail to="xxx" from="xxx" subject="xxxx ORDER No. #orderno#" server="xxx"  username="xx" password="xxx" type="html">

<img src="http://www.mmprint.com/index_files/maillogo.jpg" width="500" height="85" />         <br /><br /> <font face="Arial" size="+3"><strong>NEW LIVE JOB - <font   color="##FF0000">CMS-1500 BLANK </font> Form Order No. <cfoutput>#orderno#</cfoutput>   </strong>
 <table border="1" bordercolor="##660000" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h2>CMS-1500 Order Information:</h2></td>
</tr>

 <tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Quantity:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.qty#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Type:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.cctype#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">CC Number:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.ccnumber#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">CC Month:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.ccmonth#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">CC Year:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.ccyear#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">CSV:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.csv#</td>
</tr>

<!-- Billing Info -->
<tr>
<td><h2>Billing Information:</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Company Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.bconame#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">First Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.bfname#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Last Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.blname#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.baddress#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.baddress2#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.bcity#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.bstate#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.bzip#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Email:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.email#</td>
</tr>       
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Comments:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.comments#</td>
</tr>



</table>
<br />
<br />

<!-- SHIPPING INFO -->
<table border="1" bordercolor="##660000" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><h2>Shipping Information:</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Company Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.coname#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">First Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.fname#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Last Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.lname#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.address#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address 2:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.address2#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">City:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.city#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">State:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.state#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Zip:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.zip#</td>
</tr>
</table>
 </font>
 </cfmail>

 <cfmail to="#form.email#" from="xxx" bcc="xxx" subject="Thank You for your order - No. #orderno#" server="xxx" username="xxx" password="xxx" type="html">

<p><img src="xxx" width="500" height="85" /></p>
<p><font face="Arial" size="+1"><strong><font color="##006600">Order Confirmation-                   </font>- No. <cfoutput>#orderno#</cfoutput> </strong>
</font></p>

<font face="Arial" size="1"><p>Your order for <cfoutput>#qty#</cfoutput>xxx has been successfully received.</p>
<p>If your order is received by 2PM (ET) they will ship the same day!</p>
<p>Questions or Comments? Please call us at 1-877-mmprint or 516-334-1603 or email info@mmprint.com </p></font>


<table border="1" bordercolor="##660000" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><h2>Shipping Information:</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Company Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.coname#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">First Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.fname#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Last Name:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.lname#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.address#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Address 2:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.address2#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">City:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.city#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">State:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.state#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="##CCCCCC" align="left" valign="top">Zip:</td><td align="left" valign="top">#form.zip#</td>
</tr>

</table>



</cfmail>



<cflocation url="thanks.cfm?name=#form.bfname#" addtoken="no">
```

HERE IS THE FORM ITSELF:

```
<form action="process.cfm" id="blank-form" method="post" class="vertical">
  <div class="col_4 ">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Choose Your Quantity:</legend>
      <p>
        <select id="qty" name="qty"  size="4" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Please Select a Quantity." >
          <option value="100 Blank">100 &nbsp; - Blank CMS 1500 </option>
          <option value="250 Blank">250 &nbsp; - Blank CMS 1500 </option>
          <option value="500 Blank ">500 &nbsp; - Blank CMS 1500 </option>
          <option value="1000 Blank">1000 - Blank CMS 1500 </option>
        </select>
      </p> <div style="font-size:0.7em; text-align:right;">*plus shipping and handling</div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- CREDIT CARD -->
    <fieldset>
    <legend><i class="icon-lock"></i> Payment Information </legend>
    <label for="cctype">Type</label>
      <select id="cctype" name="cctype" data-validation="required">
      <option value="VISA">VISA</option>
      <option value="MC">Mastercard</option>
      <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
      <option value="DISC">Discover</option>
    </select>

    <label for="ccnumber">Credit Card Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="ccnumber" name="ccnumber" data-validation="number" data-validation-error-msg="Please Enter a Valid Credit Card Number." >

   <div class="col_5"> <label for="ccmonth">Expiration</label>
    <select name="ccmonth" id="ccmonth" data-validation="required">
    <option value = "1">January</option>
<option value = "2">February</option>
<option value = "3">March</option>
<option value = "4">April</option>
<option value = "5">May</option>
<option value = "6">June</option>
<option value = "7">July</option>
<option value = "8">August</option>
<option value = "9">September</option>
<option value = "10">October</option>
<option value = "11">November</option>
<option value = "12">December</option> 
</select></div>
   <div class="col_4"> <label for="ccyear">Year</label>
    <select  name="ccyear" id="ccyear" data-validation="required">
     <option value = "2014" >2014</option>
<option value = "2015">2015</option>
<option value = "2016">2016</option>
<option value = "2017">2017</option>
<option value = "2018">2018</option>
<option value = "2019">2019</option>
<option value = "2020">2020</option>
    </select></div>

     <div class="col_3"><label for="csv" >CSV #</label>
    <input type="text"  name="csv" id="csv"  data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="&nbsp;"></div>


    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend>Email &amp; Phone</legend>

    <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com"  name="email" id="email" data-validation="email" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter a valid email where you can receive your order confirmation.">
    <input type="text" placeholder="555-505-5050"  name="phone" id="phone" data-validation="number" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter a phone number where we can contact you."></fieldset>
    </div>
  <div class="col_4">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Billing Information</legend>

     <p><input type="checkbox" id="sameasbilling"> Ship to Same As Billing Address</p>

      <label for="bconame">Company Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="bconame"  name="bconame" minlength="2"/>
      <label for="bfname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="bfname"  name="bfname" minlength="2" data-validation="required"/>
      <label for="blname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="blname"  name="blname" minlength="2" data-validation="required"/>
      <label for="baddress">Address</label>
      <input type="text" id="baddress"  name="baddress" minlength="2" data-validation="required"/>
      <label for="baddress2">Suite/Apt #</label>
      <input type="text" id="baddress2" name="baddress2"  />
      <label for="bcity">City</label>
      <input type="text" id="bcity" name="bcity" data-validation="required" />
      <label for="bstate">State</label>
      <input type="text" id="bstate" name="bstate" minlength="2" data-validation="required" />
      <label for="bzip">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" id="bzip"  name="bzip" minlength="5" data-validation="required"/>

    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="col_4" id="shipping">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Shipping Information</legend><br><br>
       <label for="coname">Company Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="coname"  name="coname" minlength="2" />
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname"  name="fname" minlength="2" data-validation="required"/>
      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname"  name="lname" minlength="2" data-validation="required" />
      <label for="address">Address</label>
      <input type="text" id="address"  name="address" minlength="2" data-validation="required"/>
      <label for="address2">Suite/Apt #</label>
      <input type="text" id="address2" name="address2" />
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" data-validation="required"/>
      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type="text" id="state" name="state" minlength="2" data-validation="required"/>
      <label for="zip">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" id="zip"  name="zip" minlength="5" data-validation="required" />
     </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Comments | Special Instructions</legend>
 <textarea id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
        <div class="right">
  <button class="pop orange">Send the order!</button></div>
</form>
```

THE JQUERY:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#sameasbilling').change(function(){
if ($('#sameasbilling').is(':checked')){
    $('#shipping :input').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled',  true).attr("value","Same As Billing");

} else {
    $('#shipping :input').removeClass('disabled').prop('disabled',  false).removeAttr("value");

    }
});
 $.validate();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can simply use 
     `<cfparam name="form.name" default = "Default text">`

to replace the missing fields when the form is processed.

I only accept this solution because my form is short. I'm sure there is a better way to do this for bigger forms that handle lots of data.

Hope this will help someone else.